# Big Three Expression: crtlsvalidHeapPointer(block)

Tags: c++

I keep getting an error of "Expression: crtlsvalidHeapPointer(block)"

When I run the program, it executes all the way to the end but it triggers this error.

I believe I created big three expression. making deep copying and deleting previous address.

Is there I am missing point of creating big three expression?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//between 0 and 255
class color {
    int *red, *green, *blue;
public:
    color() {
        red = new int; green = new int; blue = new int;
        *red = 0; *green = 0; *blue = 0; }
    color(int r, int g, int b) {
        if (r < 0 || r>255)
            r = 0;
        if (g < 0 || g>255)
            g = 0;
        if (b < 0 || b>255)
            b = 0;
        red = new int;
        green = new int;
        blue = new int;
        *red = r;
        *green = g;
        *blue = b;
    }
    color(const color &rhs) :red(new int), green(new int), blue(new int) { *this = rhs; }
    color & operator=(const color &rhs) {
        if (this == &rhs)
            return *this;
        delete red;
        delete green;
        delete blue;
        red = rhs.red;
        green = rhs.green;
        blue = rhs.blue;
        return *this;
    }
    ~color() {
        delete red;
        delete green;
        delete blue;
    };
    color & operator +(const color & rhs) {
        int r, g, b;
        r = *red + *rhs.red;
        if (r > 255)
            r = 255;
        g = *green + *rhs.green;
        if (g > 255)
            g = 255;
        b = *blue + *rhs.blue;
        if (b > 255)
            b = 255;
        color *thecolor = new color(r, g, b);
        return *thecolor;
    }

    color & operator /(const color &rhs) {
        int r, g, b;
        if (*red == 0 || *rhs.red == 0)
            r = 0;
        else
            r = *red / (*rhs.red);
        if (*green == 0 || *rhs.green == 0)
            g = 0;
        else
            g = *green / (*rhs.green);
        if (*blue == 0 || *rhs.blue == 0)
            b = 0;
        else
            b = *blue / (*rhs.blue);

        color *newcolor = new color(r, g, b);
        return *newcolor;
    }



    int getred() const { return *red; }
    int getgreen()const { return *green; }
    int getblue() const { return *blue; }
    void set_red(int r) { *red = r; }
    void set_green(int g) { *green = g; }
    void set_blue(int b) { *blue = b; }
    friend ostream &operator <<(ostream &out, const color &c) {
        out << "(" << c.getred() << ", " << c.getgreen() << ", " << c.getblue() << ")";
        return out;
    }

};

int main() {
    color c1(100, 150, 220);

    color c2(23, 100, 76);

    color c3(c1);

    color c4 = c2;

    //testing << operator

    cout << "c1: " << c1 << endl;

    cout << "c2: " << c2 << endl;

    cout << "c3: " << c3 << endl;

    cout << "c4: " << c4 << endl;

    cout << "testing + and / operators" << endl;

    cout << "c1+c2: " << c1 + c2 << endl;

    cout << "c1/c2: " << c1 / c2 << endl;


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why does `class color` have `int *red, *green, *blue;` and not `int red, green, blue;` ?

Comment: In `color & operator=(const color &rhs)` the lines like `red = rhs.red;` mean that `red` and `rhs.red` both point to (and think they own) the same block of memory this will cause double deletes.  If you have to use pointers use `std::unique_ptr` .

Comment: In `color & operator +(const color & rhs)` doing `color *thecolor = new color(r, g, b);` creates a memory leak, just do `return color(r, g, b);`  Same for `color & operator /(const color &rhs)`   Not an exact duplicate but please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading